# have images side by side with overflow in a div

Tags: html, css

So i want to show a image inside of a border, then have about 2-3 images behind that image but i want only the first part of the first image to be seen.
Something like this:

[image: example]

Then i need all the numbers outside of the border to be hidden, but there should be 2-3 more of these images next to the first, but hidden.

Is there a way to do that?

edit:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="roulette">
    <img src="../application/views/img/cases.png">
    <img src="../application/views/img/cases.png">
    <img src="../application/views/img/cases.png">
    <img src="../application/views/img/cases.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I have a question. I made this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s5jnnqjc/ but why is the overflow:hidden not working in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide elements inside div, by using **overflow: hidden;** 
By using **float: left;** images stand side by side. So, below code, I have many images but only 8 are showing rest are hidden;

```css
.roulette{ 
width: 200px; 
height: 25px; 
outline: 2px solid red; 
overflow:hidden; 
float:left; 
} 

.roulette img{ 
width: 25px; /*8 images for .roulette{*/ 
height: 25px; 
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="roulette">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.bareinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/number-1.png">
    <img src="https://www.favorsandflowers.com/images/D/Number-2-Rhinestone-Cake-Topper-D.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: i tried doing `float: left;` but they stayed underneath eachother

Answer (score 1):

I made a div

style= height 20 px and width 20 px (you can enter your values)

style = border-line: solid and border-width: 5px (you can enter your values)

And the most important part: overflow:hidden

If overflow is visible, then the picture will be shown as it is, regardless of the div, and if it is hidden, then it will be only shown that what fits in the div's height and width

*Edited: by placing them one after another, they will be side by side 
Also, what I can recommend, is to use SPANS for that purpose

*Edited 2: Changed the snippet, added a large image, and integrated 2 buttons to move it's position

Now you can just (in paint or something) make 1 large image instead of 3 small ones, in order to make this a rulet like shifting :)

Hope I could help.

```js
function getPosition() {
  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  alert("Coordinates: " + rect.left + "px, " + rect.top + "px");
}

function scrollImgLeft() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.getElementById("img").style.position= "relative";
    document.getElementById("img").style.left = (rect.left - 20) + "px"; 
}

function scrollImgRight() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.getElementById("img").style.position= "relative";
    document.getElementById("img").style.left = (rect.left + 20) + "px"; 
}
```

```html
<div style="height:40px; width: 120px; border-line: solid; border-width: 5px; overflow:hidden">
  <img id="img" src="https://www.theroomplace.com/images/theroomplace/content/global/header-16.2/digital-catalog.jpg" >
</div>

 <button onclick="scrollImgLeft()">Left</button> 
  <button onclick="scrollImgRight()">Right</button> 
 <button onclick="getPosition()">Get Position</button>
```

Comment: it kind of worked i noly see the first image for a little bit, but they are still underneath eachother even if i use `float: left;`

Comment: And you want them to be besides one another?

Comment: yes, whati eventually want to do is have about 3 of the same images next to eachother with only a little bit of the first image to be seen, then when a button is clicked scroll the 3 images to the left a random amount of pixels

Comment: just add the next img right after the first one, I just updated the answer

Comment: this wouldn't make any difference if i put them side by side in the code right?
tried it nevertheless, but it doesn't work

Comment: I added a snippet, I have there 3 images side by side, but the third one is not shown, bc it is out of range for the div

Comment: that's weird, i have the exact same but mine are underneath eachother.
could this be because the images are larger than the screen width?

Comment: y It could be :)

Comment: Try it now, you just need to combine the 3 pictures into 1, and run the code in the snippet